# Multiplication of three 0-1 decision variables

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, binary-programming

I have an optimization problem that its objective has a multiplication of three 0-1 decision variables. I don't want to introduce a new variables that equal their multiplication and add the needed constraints as the number of variables will increase to reach 1.5 Million.

Any recommendations?

Comment: The multiplication of any positive number of $0-1$ decision variables is $1$ if they are all $1$ and is $0$ otherwise.  So either they are all $1$ (you can check the consequences) or you can ignore this term

Comment: They are decision variables. That are $x_i$ for $i=1,..34$, $y_j$ for $j=1,..,158$, and $z_k$ for $k=1,..,200$. So, for the same $x$ it can be 0 and 1 depending of the index.